# how to customize android app theme

Tags: android, themes

I am new to Android App programming. I am working on Android Studio 0.4.3 on Ubuntu 12.04. It occurs to me that if I select Holo.dark as my theme, the next time I open my project it will fail to reload the theme and tell me the theme is missing. So the only theme I can use is Appcompat. And if I change that in style.xml by changing the parent of the style to "android:Theme.Holo", it will cause some bugs. Can anyone tell me how to use these themes, and how to create some more beautiful customized theme, or where to find beautiful themes that other people have written ( like bootstrap for css )? Thank you very much!